# Swift 2: Spawn sprite every 400 pixels

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

Looking for a way to have a sprite spawn with a gap of 400 pixels between. So for each 400 pixels i see in the horizontal direction there is a sprite.

I will gradually be moving towards the right and in a varying speed so I don't think a moveByX is possible to use in this case.

This is the code i have now:

```
 override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

     self.enemyTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: "spawning", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
 }

    func spawning() {

    let enemyTowardsTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "enemy")
    let enemyTowards = SKSpriteNode(texture: enemyTowardsTexture)
    enemyTowards.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame) + self.frame.size.width, y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    enemyTowards.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: enemyTowardsTexture, size: enemyTowardsTexture.size())
    enemyTowards.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = true
    self.addChild(enemyTowards)

    enemyTimer.invalidate()
    resetTimer()

}

    func resetTimer() {

        self.enemyTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(5.0, target: self, selector: "spawning", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

Comment: You should use `SKAction` instead of `NSTimer`.

Comment: Also, you should "think" in points, not pixels...Coordinates are measured in points in SpriteKit...